# Why is my android app not responding when there is no internet connection?

Tags: java, android

My apps loads a webpage from the internet. When there is no internet connection it  should show a message in the webview that it is going to connect to the internet again and then it should try to connect. But when I test my app it doesn't show the ui until it has an internet connection. How can this be fixed?

```
public class ma extends Fragment {

String dag = "1";
public WebView webViewma;

@Override
@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ma, container, false);
    webViewma = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewma);
    LaadRooster();
    return v;

}


public void LaadRooster() {


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://foo.com/foo.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dag", dag));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        if (ret.startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")) {
            webViewma.loadData(ret, "text/html", null);



        } else {
            webViewma.loadData("No connection, trying again...", "text/html", null);
            LaadRooster();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
                        webViewma.loadData("No connection, trying again...", "text/html", null);
        LaadRooster();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably your application is running a single thread. Get the httpresponse from inside another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are locking up your UI by doing an HTTP request on the main thread. This needs to be moved to a background thread.

Also, it might be easier to check to see if the device is connected to the internet this way:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] allNetworks = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : allNetworks) {
        if (networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```